# Create elegant urls avoiding querystrings using native RegisterRoutes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes, friendly-url

this is the url that currently is generated for a property detail page.

```
http://localhost:61346/Property/Details?strap=0001020005
```

I want this to read

```
http://localhost:61346/Property/Details/0001020005
```

Here are my registered routes.  Is this something simple to setup in MVC3?  Extra points for explaining how to setup 'RegisterRoutes' for this format

`http://localhost:61346/Property/0001020005`  <--simply hides the action name

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


            routes.MapRoute(
                   "Property", // Route name
                   "{controller}/{action}/{ParcelId}", // URL with parameters
                   new { controller = "Property", action = "List", ParcelId = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
               );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
"Details", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Property", action = "Details" } // Parameter defaults
);         


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map your URLs a bit cleaner, you just need to map the values in the URL to the params in your action method.  Since you are using `strap`, you need a route that maps it, much like your "Property" route:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    "PropDetails", // Route name 
    "{controller}/{action}/{strap}", // URL with parameters 
    new { controller = "Property", action = "Details" }
);
```

Note, though, that your routes are going to be used in the order in which you define them.  Thus, in the ones you listed, `Default` and `Details` will never actually be used since `Property` will catch them all.  Instead, you might want something more like:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    "PropDetails", // Route name 
    "Property/Details/{strap}", // URL with parameters 
    new { controller = "Property", action = "Details" }
);
```

This will ensure that only routes matching `/Property/Details/{strap}` will be affected (like your example URL) and you won't have a false-positive with `/Something/Else/`.

To answer your question about {id}, that's just something that is defined in the route.  You can name that whatever you want, such as {strap}.  But if you rewrite your action methods to accept a `string ID`, then you will lose the query string without having to modify your routes.

```
public ActionResult Details (string id) { ... }  // Don't have to modify your routes
public ActionResult Details (string strap) { ... } // Have to modify your routes to remove the querystring
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `Details` and `Property` routes and change your `Details` and `List` action methods to accept `string id` as an argument your default route should pick up that format.  Your `Property`route is in conflict with the default route.

The format you desire is compatible with the default route.  You just need to change your argument names to accomodate handling this.

`public ActionResult Details(string id){...}`

and

`public ActionResult List(string id){...}`

and

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)  {
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");    
  routes.MapRoute(
                 "Default", // Route name
                 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id =UrlParameter.Optional  
                 });
}
```

Comment: is `id` some sort of reserved word?

Comment: No it could be whatever you want it to be `id=UrlParameter.Optional` and `{id}` is where that is coming from.